# Complex anti-derivative and the path integral property

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I am confused how the existence of a complex anti derivative on an open set implies the path integral property. The proof of this is shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiderivative_(complex_analysis)#Necessity%22here%22) and it is very simple.

Is this not a trivial counter example?

$$U = \{ z \in \Bbb C : |z| > 0.5 \space \land |z| <1.5 \} $$
$$g(z):=1/z$$

I believe $g(z)$ has an anti-derivative on all of $U$ but $\int_\gamma g(z)dz = 0$ on $\gamma$ of a unit circle.

This would make more sense if the requirement was $U$ is simply connected, but that requirement does not seem to be used in the proof. What am I missing?

Comment: What is the antiderivative of g in U?

Comment: Is it not just natural log of z?

Comment: That function is not defined on the whole annulus.

Comment: Where is it not defined? Sorry if it is obvious.

Comment: We can define $G(z) = \operatorname{Arg}(z)$ on all of $U$ but it will be discontinuous, and therefore its derivative is not defined everywhere. Then $G$ is not an antiderivative of $g$ on all of $U$.

Comment: @md2perpe Wow that makes sense. Basically since you have to pick a branch of the log function (or else it would be multi valued) this will make it discontinuous when the argument resets? And I guess there is some deep reason why this happens that has to do with the pole at zero. Thanks!

Comment: @md2perpe Feel free to write this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can define $G(z) = \operatorname{Arg}(z)$ on all of $U$ but it will be discontinuous, and therefore its derivative is not defined everywhere. Then $G$ is not an antiderivative of $g$ on all of $U$.